# Solspace and Structure conflict?

Tags: php, channel, structure, solspace-calendar, calendar

[image: This is what it looks like when I go to Publish Calendar->calendars]

So this is my problem.  I am using Structure for a site.  But, I am also using Solspace Calender-- particularly for the ICS function more than anything. (So, if there is another option out there that would allow calendar population from an external ICS file... that would be another option that I'd be open to...), but as it is  I have read around and it seems that as long as I'm not using the same template group and/or Structure is not using /calendar (url) that I should be able to use Solspace Calendar from my understanding.  Version-wise Solspace is using 1.8.6 on EE 2.7.1 and PHP Version 5.3.27.

I've installed and reinstalled a number of times and cannot get the "TIMEZONE" area under Calendar->Calendars to appear. / or a calendar entry that I publish to be recognized when I go to publish an event as I constantly get the "You must first create a calendar before creating an event." Message under the DATES & OPTIONS tab.

What am I doing wrong & / overlooking here??

Comment: I'm not sure this has anything to do with Structure. Does it work with Structure uninstalled?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Yes, it does work with Structure uninstalled.  It is only when Structure is installed that I am getting this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the channels and custom field groups provided by Calendar when it's installed.

To create events in "Calendar: Events", you need to create a calendar in "Calendar: Calendars" first.

If you uninstalled Calendar and want to reinstall it, make sure to delete everything from the old Calendar install before you do, this includes the old Calendar channels and the custom field groups created to be used with these old Calendar channels. The "Timezone" field not displaying anything might be caused by a lingering channel/custom field group.

*Also make sure to upload the Calendar themes folder!*

Comment: I have a feeling that a lingering channel/custom field group may have been the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Seems after not being able to find anything happening and following every hunch I could.  It miraculously started worked after another uninstall -> reinstall.  Thank you all for you help.